# How to retrieve data from a dynamically generated form?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I am having problems getting information out of forms that have been dynamically generated by the program.

My program runs until it needs data from the user; at which point it should run an input form, and retrieve data from it.

The below example code runs and displays the input form, but does not allow any input to it. It does return the length of the text in the edit box at initialisation of the form.

What is incorrect in this approach?

If possible I want to maintain the overall approach of seperating interfaces and implementation (including forms); I also want to continue to use modeless display of forms.

**EDIT**

After investigation of modal forms as suggested by @Ken White, I determined that modal forms were not appropriate for what I was trying to do. I came up with a solution, summarized as:

1. Two interfaces:
2. IResult - defined to carry the required data from the form to UserInput.
3. IUserInput - obtain user input from a form in an IResult.
4. Two creator functions - one for each Interface.
5. Implementation of the interfaces - one object for each interface, and one for the actual user input form.

I have written a [detailed description](http://delphi-divertimentos.blogspot.com/2011/11/system-generated-and-managed-user-input.html) of this solution.

**END EDIT**

```
program TestProject2;

uses Dialogs, Forms, StdCtrls, SysUtils;

type
  ITestForm = interface
    function getFormString: string;
    procedure setFormString(aString: string);
  end;

  TForm6 = class(TForm, ITestForm)
    Edit1: TEdit;
  private
    function getFormString: string;
    procedure setFormString(aString: string);
  end;

{$R Unit6.dfm}

function NewTestFormOutput: string;
  var
    tmpForm: TForm6;
  begin
    Application.CreateForm(TForm6, tmpForm);
    tmpForm.Show;
    Result := tmpForm.getFormString;
  end;

function TForm6.getFormString: string;
  begin
    Result := Edit1.Text;
  end;

procedure TForm6.setFormString(aString: string);
  begin
    Edit1.Text := aString;
  end;

var
  i: Integer;
  parser: string;
begin
  parser := NewTestFormOutput;
  i := Length(parser);
  ShowMessage('The length is: ' + InttoStr(i));
end.
```

Answer (score 6):

Your code as you posted it doesn't allow the user to provide any input before it retrieves the content of `TForm6.Edit1.Text`. You basically say:

1. Create the form
2. Show it to the user
3. Immediately read whatever was set at designtime in the form's Edit1.Text

If you want to get content from the user, you have to give them a chance to give it to you. You need to either use `ShowModal` to present the form and let the user enter content, or use `Show` and have the form pass back information (via some mechanism like `PostMessage` or an event handler, as Gerry mentioned in his comment) when the user clicks a button to let you know there's data to retrieve.

The point is still, though, that you have to allow the user a chance to provide input before you can retrieve it.

Comment: or via a callback (event handler) function

Comment: I am probably being very stupid, but I do not understand how to give the user a chance to provide input. I am concentrating on your response to Show, rather than to ShowModal. Do I have to put a delay loop in NewTestForm? Do I have to put a do..while loop there that terminates on receipt of an event from the input form? Do I have to provide the callback function as a parameter to the form creation? Or is the way of doing this something that I am completely missing?

Comment: @Chris: I'd like to post code, but it's not clear exactly what you're trying to do. You can use `ShowModal` instead, or you can assign an event handler in the creating code to a `TButton.OnClick` on the child form; when the child form's button is clicked, the event handler in the creating code is called, at which point it can read the user input. Does that help?

Comment: @Ken Thanks your comments do help, as does the comment about callbacks - which I am currently investigating. As to what I am trying to do is have a program (with no main form) obtain user input at a point in its execution. I am trying to do this by the program creating a user form; getting input from it; and destroying the form once it has the input. As in the example, I am coding using interfaces. The example code is very simple - my actual user form is complicated; and the retrieved data is a complex record structure.

Comment: @Chris: If your app needs user input to continue, you should be showing the form modally, and not proceeding until the user provides the necessary input. Especially if the retrieved data is a complex record - don't you need all the input for it?

Comment: @Ken Fair comment on modal usage. I will reconsider my perceived requirement to provide form concurrency. I anticipated that the program would generate multiple input forms, which could be in use at the same time. It is my understanding that use of modal forms prevents input to any other forms.

Comment: @Chris: Can your app proceed on only partial input? If not, you should present a single modal dialog (even if it needs multiple pages of info, like in a wizard-type presentation), collect all of the info, and then retrieve it from the calling code if `ShowModal` returns `mrOk` (or whatever successful result you decide to use). Multiple input forms to collect data that is required to proceed would seem confusing, from my point of view (which is of my screen, not yours, and can't see your app's specific needs <g>).

Comment: @Chris: I'll do the same. Nice discussion. :)